# Is there any way to alter the url of a FileField in Django?

Tags: python, django

FileField objects have a url attribute. How do I alter it? The docs say it is read-only. Is there even a way to alter the underlying storage class? I am working with a migrated database and can't get the urls of the old directory structure to apply the new deployment. The MEDIA_ROOT is set fine, upload_to is being used in models, so new objects get saved correctly, but old ones are expected to be in the MEDIA_ROOT by the application, which is not the case.

Comment: Generally Django's FileField gets saved as varchar in database, so you can directly change it in Db with SQL query or try updating the name in the django shell.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15590 says fixed

Comment: Thank you for your participation here. I was able to edit the *file* attribute of my FileField object but not the url attribute. This suffices.

Comment: Why don't you move the old files from old directory structure to the new structure? The url (when using a `FileSystemStorage`) is just [a "computed" property](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/files/storage.py#L288) that joins the base url (MEDIA_URL) with the file directory structure from the root (MEDIA_ROOT).

Comment: Because the name attribute of a FileField seems to be a full path appended to media root. Old project was just a filename.

Answer (score 2):

From your model get all instance and change the name attribute.
For example in your model you ave a Many-to-many relationships to a document.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    doc_file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_path, max_length=500)
    
class Repository(models.Model):
   documents = models.ManyToManyField(Document)
```

...

```
for doc in Repository.documents.all():
    doc.doc_file.name = new_full_path
    doc.save()
```

Another way is use Query Expressions

```
Repository.document.all().update(
    documents =Func(
        F('documents'),
        Value(old_path), Value(new_path),
        function='replace'
    )
)
```